# Symfony : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB

Tags: xampp

I work on a database with geomatry type data and which is an already existing database. So when I import my "collecte" table which contains the spatial data to make it an Entity at symfony level it gives me this error above.

I want to import my "collecte" table which contains the spatial data
my command to import the table: php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import App\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity

my .env:DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/db_geoapp?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.8"